# Applying a class type to a property in state in react native

Tags: react-native

I created a class in react native.

```
import Author from "./authorDetails";

class MainFeedPost {
  id;
  description;
  postImage;
  author;
  creationDateTime;
  version;
  status;
  extra = {
    likes,
    shares,
    comments
  };

  constructor() {
    this.author = new Author();
  }
}

export default MainFeedPost;
```

Now I want to set this as a type in one of my components state. I tried it like this an it is undefined.

```
import { MainFeedPost } from "../../models";

class SharePostScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      post: MainFeedPost
    };
  }
```

doesn't this support in react native? I want to initialize the shape of my object with MainFeedPost class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told "as a type". If you want static type checking, you need something like [flow](http://flow.org).
If you wanna value in the state, you must place there an instance:

```
...
this.state = {
  post: new MainFeedPost(),
};
...
```

UPD:
I got your point. Because of `default` export you need to use `import MainFeedPost from "..."`, without braces.

Comment: what exactly? Clarify pls what you wanna get

Comment: I want to shape my post property of my state, according to the MainFeedPost class. 

I want to set my post, the type of MainFeedPost.

Comment: Thanks Kirill for the helpful answer.